# What tense is 使って in これを使ってここで動画を作っています?

Tags: て-form

In

> これを**使って**ここで動画を作っています

does 作っています being in the present progressive tense then force 使って to also be in the present progressive? Or would the sentence have to be written as

> これを**使っていて**ここで動画を作っています?

in order for the first verb to in the present progressive?

Alternatively, is 使って is in non-past tense while 作っています is in present progressive tense?

Answer (score 4):

I’m not sure what exactly you are asking, but the て-form remains unaffected by the tense or aspect of the main clause.

> これを使ってここで動画を作ります。
> これを使ってここで動画を作っています。
> これを使ってここで動画を作りました。
> これを使ってここで動画を作っていました。

That’s if you want 使って to denote the means by which you make the movies. If you said これを使っていて〜, this relationship would get lost. You would be simply connecting two independent statements in one sentence.

> これを使っていて、ここで動画を作っています。
> I’m using this and I’m making the movies here.

Answer (score 3):

～て here is being used moreso with an adverbial/gerundive function (≈ -ing) (i.e. the first clause somehow modifies, describes, or is subordinate to the second), rather than as an "and"-type sequential clause connector. As aguijonazo mentioned in their reply, 使って here indicates means of action (cf. the particle で).

「これを使ってここで動画を作っています。」

"I make videos here (by means of) using this."

Another example of the same use of 使って would be「ナイフを使ってリンゴを切った」"I cut the apple using a knife" (a translation with "and" also works, though note that an "and" here still wouldn't indicate chronological or logical sequence).

Of course, this isn't limited to just 使う (e.g.「二人は声を揃えて歌い始めた」).

Comment: I would further argue that “and” as way of translation and probably harmful to teach it that way, especially as it's main function. It's always an adverbial gerundive, and a better way to understand something such as say “朝ご飯を食べて学校に行った。” grammatically is “I went to school after eating breakfast.” not “I ate breakfast and went to school.”

Comment: Grammatically て _is_ always adverbial. At the same time "I ate breakfast and went to school" is the better translation for your example (the "after eating" ver. more closely corresponds to 食べてから). Personally, I see no point in forcing (subtly) awkward translations just for the sake of syntactic alignment between two different languages with different idiom. て does often mean "and". Likening it to the adverbial gerundive _can_ be helpful mechanically, but you can also just explain the mechanics of it in its own terms, and "-ing" as a catch-all translation is certainly inaccurate/insufficient.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree. There are many cases where I would feel “after eating” is more natural as a translation, or “while eating” or “despite eating”. It's true that in some contexts “and” feels more natural but many sources teach the te-form's default interpretation as “and” as though it be a conjunction. While “and” is I feel actually an exceptional interpretation. Similar to how, say, “難しすぎて読めない” is often best translated to “too difficult to read”. The default interpretation should be seen as “-ing”, the rest is liberal translations to make it appear more idiomatic.